# Сборка демо-версии приложения Android/Java

Tags: android, gradle

Хочется пополнить свой портфолио приложений, но выполняю заказы, которые не выходят в общий доступ.
**Как сделать помимо `debug`  и `release` ещё сборку `demo`, который будет брать интерфейс и логику, но не будет брать информацию о сервере (вместо него использовать `assets` - которые недоступны в `debug` и  `release`)**
Я предполагаю, что это будет видоизмененный `debug`

Comment: Решите какую-нибудь простенькую задачу, скажем, список погоды в городах с графиками температуры, выложите код на гитхаб и приложение в маркет, если хочется - это будет одним из лучших способов украсить портфолио :)

Comment: Хочется продемонстрировать именно коммерческие решения

Answer (score 0):

**Прямого и понятного пути создать демку из уже существующего приложения - нет**. Нужно разбирать каждый конкретный случай. В общем должно быть примерно следующее: нужно сделать фейки для всех классов, которые общаются с сервером, эти фейки должны активироваться (и находится в `classpath` вместо реальных классов, общающихся с сервером), когда вы собираете демку, в основном же приложении этих классов быть не должно. Далее, какая-то часть логики, видимо, тоже должна быть сокрыта. Нужно делать тоже самое: сделать заглушку к уже существующей логике. Далее, дизайн. Возможно, что-то из дизайна придется не выкладывать в демку, поэтому нужно будет сделать тоже самое: заглушку. Как обычно реализовывают заглушки? Можно сделать два модуля, в одном сложить классы для релизного приложения, в другом сложить классы (с тем же самым названием и пакетом) для демки. А в основном `build.gradle` сделать так:

```
debugImplementation project(path: ':network-release')
releaseImplementation project(path: ':network-release')
demoImplementation project(path: ':network-demo')
```

где `debug`, `release` и `demo` - это [buildType](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Answer (score 0):

Когда возникла задача сделать free/paid версии одного приложения, (по сути free - это обрезанная paid, как и в вашем случае), я использовал очень удобную функцию Android Studio:  ["product flavors".](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors)